# How can I execute a SQL script before each INSERT using Pentaho Spoon?

Tags: pentaho, sap-ase, kettle

I am trying to use Spoon to migrate a database from a PostgreSQL database into a Sybase installation.

The problem I am facing right now is that Sybase has this mode you have to enable whenever you want to set an id explicitly. You have to execute the command `SET IDENTITY_INSERT table_name ON`, that will enable inserting data specifying ids for the current connection.

Is it possible to setup a transformation to execute that before a "Table output" step, using the same connection that will be used to insert the data?

Or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into this and it's annoying. What I ended up doing is making a custom connection definition for each table that has an identity to insert.

In the custom connection definition, there is an advanced tab. On the advanced tab there is a space to enter custom SQL that get executed immediately after connecting. Put your SET statement in there, then select that connection in your table output step.

This is a common enough problem in both Sybase and MS SQL Server I should probably post it as a feature request to Pentaho.

Brian

Comment: Nice, I'm glad at least there is a way to workaround it! It would be nice to have some support for this in Pentaho, in my case it were a big bunch of tables... I can't test it for now, but I'm marking your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If this ID is for a data warehouse, you might want to consider using the {Dimension lookup/update} step (in the Data Warehouse folder) to manage the surrogate key for you.  This step non-optionally adds row versioning, though, which can be awkward if you don't need it.

Otherwise, perhaps you could use the {Execute SQL script} step, either in-line or in a separate transformation, to issue the {SET} command.

Comment: I've tried the step {Execute SQL script} already, but it does not work in the same transaction/connection even inline with {Table output}. I'm giving up using Spoon for this migration and I'm creating a Groovy script for it, thanks a lot for your attention.